# Creating new dataframe columns based on dict from each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                                                   0                                                  1
0  {'time': '1662249600', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 4...  {'time': '1663459200', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 1...
1  {'time': '1662336000', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 5...  {'time': '1663545600', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 1...
2  {'time': '1662422400', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 6...  {'time': '1663632000', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 2...
3  {'time': '1662508800', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 7...  {'time': '1663718400', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 2...
4  {'time': '1662595200', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 8...  {'time': '1663804800', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 2...
```

where each cell looks like this:
`{'time': '1662249600', 'formattedTime': 'Sep 4, 2022', 'value': 47, 'formattedValue': '47', 'isPartial': False}`

How can I pull a specific value (e.g. `time`) from each dict and add it to new columns. The result would be something like this:

```
   time_0       time_1
0  1662249600   1663459200
1  1662336000   1663545600
2  1662422400   1663632000
3  1662508800   1663718400
4  1662595200   1663804800
```

Comment: what was the original data source format? json?

Comment: try this, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Comment: Please specify your input data structure. Is it "dict of dicts" in format {{time, formattedTime}, {time, formattedTime},...} or smth else?

Comment: Yes, the original data comes from json, which I put into a dataframe and then split into two columns

Comment: Updated with the data structure of each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data inside columns are dictionaries, you can do:

```
df["time_0"] = df[0].apply(pd.Series)["time"]
df["time_1"] = df[1].apply(pd.Series)["time"]

df = df.drop([0,1], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. There might be more columns so I ended up using a loop with your solution, but it worked!